Combining Colums in two column paper layout
I am currently working on a paper, using the two column layout by the aps journal layout. For most of the 3d diagrams, I am using tikz to generate the diagrams directly in the document, using the equation environment. However, some of those diagrams get pretty bulky, and would need both colums of the paper. I have tried to find a way to achieve this, and found one for Figures, but could not find anything for equations.
The preamble:
\documentclass[%
reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, longend]{algorithm2e}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes, decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfusetitle]{hyperref} % hidelinks removes colored boxes around references and links

For the individual tikz pictures:
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=0.65]
\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{0.4cm}{0.3cm}}
\pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}

...

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

The goal would be to have a two columned layout, but have individual tikz graphics go across both of them, and blocking that space of for the main text to continue below.
Edit: Minimum viable example of the current problem, with the figure crossing into the second colums text:
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, longend]{algorithm2e}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes, decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfusetitle]{hyperref} % hidelinks removes colored boxes around references and links



\begin{document}
\section{Test Area}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=0.75]
\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{0.4cm}{0.3cm}}
\pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}
\draw (-10, 0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- (10,0,-5) -- (-10,0,-5) -- (-10,0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[6-10]


\end{document}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Added a minimum viable example, and a picture of the current output, thanks!

I'm not sure why you use an equation for a tikzpicture, but you could place it in a widetext environment:
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrhack} % necessary for listings package
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered, longend]{algorithm2e}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes, decorations.pathreplacing, shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfusetitle]{hyperref} % hidelinks removes colored boxes around references and links



\begin{document}
\section{Test Area}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{widetext}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, scale=0.75]
\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{1cm}{0cm}}
\pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{0.4cm}{0.3cm}}
\pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}
\draw (-10, 0,0) -- (10,0,0) -- (10,0,-5) -- (-10,0,-5) -- (-10,0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{widetext}
\lipsum[6-10]


\end{document}



The diagrams drawn with tikz are used as a diagrammatic expression of equations, so I want them referenced as such. But the widetext solution works brilliantly!
